# Writing zipped byte[] into file

Tags: java, nio, bytearrayoutputstream, zipoutputstream

I am trying to write a zipfile to a `byte[]` in memory, and then write that out to disk. The resulting zipfile is corrupt.

This works:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Files.createTempFile("works", ".zip").toFile());
     ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)) {
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("test.txt"));
    zos.write("hello world".getBytes());
    zos.closeEntry();
}
```

This is broken and creates a corrupt zip file:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos)) {
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("test.txt"));
    zos.write("hello world".getBytes());
    zos.closeEntry();

    Files.write(Files.createTempFile("broken", ".zip"), bos.toByteArray());
}
```

Why would the second one not work? And how can I fix it, assuming that I need to operate on a raw `byte[]` (I can't create the zip file directly into a file, since I need the `byte[]` for other purposes).

Comment: There is a more suitable format for single file compression: `test.txt.gz` using a **GZipOutputStream**.

Comment: Close `ZipOutputStream` and `FileOutputStream ` after `zos.closeEntry();`.

Comment: Why? Why not just write it direct to disk and save all that time and space?

Comment: @EJP as I noted in the question, I need the `byte[]` for other purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to flush `zos` before writing `bos`, since it won't be closed until after the try-with-resources (and therefore `zos` is not necessarily flushed through to `bos` yet when you're writing the bytes to file).

Edit: you need to call `zos.finish();` to...well finish the compression. The `close()` method will call it normally.

Comment: Doesn't help, still corrupt

Comment: How does the corrupt file differ from the intact one?

Comment: I would compare the sizes first, but see my edit about `finish()`.